# How do I fix this: "ClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ConfigurationHolder"?

Tags: grails

I was trying to run my grails project which I upgraded to 2.4.4 from 2.3.5.
Now after trying to run it, I get these error:

```
|Running Grails application
context.GrailsContextLoaderListener Error initializing the application: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ConfigurationHolder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ConfigurationHolder
    at grails.plugin.hibernate3.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure1.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:129)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:754)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    ... 8 more
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: have you also updated the hibernate plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Grail's migration doc, it looks like they have remove ConfigurationHolder from 2.4.

You need to update the hibernate plugin.

From their doc:

> Static Holder Classes The following deprecated classes have been
>   removed from Grails 2.4.x:
>
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.support.GrailsResourceLoaderHolder
>   If you or any plugins you have installed are using these classes you
>   will get a compilation error. The problem can be rectified by updating
>   to new plugins and using grails.util.Holders instead.
>
> If your application uses the jquery plugin you will need to update to
>   version 1.11.0.2 or later as previous versions of the plugin made use
>   of the ApplicationHolder class. If your application uses the resources
>   plugin you will need to update to version 1.2.7 or later as previous
>   versions of the plugin made use of the ConfigurationHolder class.

migration doc: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

Comment: Configuration Holder was removed in 1.4

Comment: and the plugin is  hibernate3.  that's what the error message is saying.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Eclipse,  go to Java build path,  Order and Export,  tick all the libraries and then execute the application

Comment: @dMcNavish After referring to the link you provided and doing changes to my BuildConfig.groovy. I got a lot of error after updating my project. See below info:

1.0.1\src\groovy\grails\plugin\mail\MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy: 21: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder

vy: 17: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder

org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\orm\auditable\AuditLogEvent.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
  [groovyc]  @ line 3, column 1.